# Lower Triangular in A=LU

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to Factor A into A=LU, where L is unit lower triangular.

A=

```
|1 -1 -2 |
|2 -3 -5 |
|-1 3 5  |
```

I have the upper triangular matrix of

```
|1 -1 -2 |
|0 -1 -1 |
|0  0  1 |
```

I can not get the lower matrix for some reason. I keep canceling out the second row and cant get pivots.

Can anyone explain to me the steps to doing so. My steps were as follows:

row3 - row2 = row2

This gives me -3 0 0. Then after this I cant get a pivot in the middle. If I do 3row1+row3=row1 I later get the same problem.

Comment: @user102650: Did the answer below resolve your issues? Regards

Answer (score 3):

We are looking for $A = LU$, but it looks like we are given $U$ and just need to find $L$, so we have:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ l_{21} & 1 & 0 \\ l_{31} & l_{32} & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} \\ 0 & u_{22} & u_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & u_{33} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -2 \\ 2 & -3 & -5 \\ -1 & 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

However, somehow you already know or are given $U$, so we have:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ l_{21} & 1 & 0 \\ l_{31} & l_{32} & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -2 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -2 \\ 2 & -3 & -5 \\ -1 & 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Solving for each of the variables, in the correct order yields:

- $l_{21} = 2$
- $l_{31} = -1, l_{32} = -2$

Note, that if we did not know $U$, we would just solve for the variables in this order.

- $u_{11}, u_{12}, u_{13}$
- $l_{21}, u_{22}, u_{23}$
- $l_{31}, l_{32}, u_{33}$

So, our final result from above is:

$$A = L \cdot U = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -2 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -2 \\ 2 & -3 & -5 \\ -1 & 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Nice work (and nice formatting, too!) ;-) +1

Comment: And you're precisely the kind of person who takes everything you do seriously; what you take on, you dedicate yourself to, and you do well! I understand the "benefit and curse" issue, though!

Comment: I love the $()$ version of showing matrices instead. ;+)